# Angular js Controllers

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular js for my front end web application...
I have encountered a problem..the problem.is..

1)In login page i am giving username and password which has one controller for this screen.

2)I have a forget password link on this screen.

3)Separate screen appears when clicked on forget password link.

4)I have a separate controller for this forget password screen.

5)I want to get username value to forget password screen when i enter username in login screen and clicked on forget password link.

6)I am trying to use a service instead of $rootscope..

Please help me on this...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post the relevant code, especially for your attempts to use a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use service to pass data between controllers. Please see Demo in plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/g622YzgpqkJStPZaNj5i?p=preview
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

```
app.controller('LoginScreenController', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {

$scope.userName = User.userName;

$scope.forgotPassword = function(userName) {
    User.userName = userName;
};
}])
.service('User', ['$window', function(win) {
this.userName = "";
}])
.controller('ForgotPasswordController', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return User.userName
}, function(newValue) {
    $scope.userName = newValue;
});

}]);
```

Comment: My  model name is "user.email"...so while calling function in login controller function(user.email)..its throwing me an error...plzz..hlp me on dis...

Comment: Quick reply: You will want to pass in html as user.emal but in controller you would do function(email). Try that.

Comment: Thnq for the reply...I have a differnt ques now..In a screen which has one controller, i am entering username filed and after clicking on submit button i want to get securityQues in a dropdwn list on the same screen (previuosly user has alrdy given the secuirtyQues details)..Plzz hlp me ..